# How to add a facebook like button to Blogger below header

Tags: facebook, blogger

Case 1: I use this code: (from http://blogzonebd.com/add-facebook-like-button-below-post-titles-in-blogspot-how-to/)

```
<iframe allowTransparency='true' 
    expr:src='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=100&amp; action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&quot;' 
    frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px;
    height:20px;'/>
```

When I click "like", a confirm button comes and when I click like in the new popup window that comes up, I am redirected to https://www.facebook.com/plugins/error/like/confirm

Case 2. I use an iframe from facebook developers:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=data:post.url&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80&amp;appId=324750880918583"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px;
    height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The `data:post.url` used under href does not give me the url of the blog, but the string itself.

Case 3. I tried the XFBML version from the link in Case 2, part of the code of which is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=324750880918583";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This is the error that blogger shows when I try to save the template.

```
Error parsing XML, line 1201, column 68: The reference to entity "appId" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Please, can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to [this](http://htmlentities.net/) site and click on encode

1.Enter the code in "input"

2.Click on encode

3.Use the new code

Answer (score 0):

Use iframe method and add your code like this:

```
<iframe allowTransparency='true' expr:src='&quot;//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot;
  + data:post.sharePostUrl +
  &quot;&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;
  height=21&quot;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'/>
```

Note the expr:src should be all in one line although above is in multiple lines for easy reading.
The idea in the expr:src is that every text you want must be inside " when you want to add blogger specific variables just concat with +.

So, above i want facebook url before blogger variable, so I just defined an expr:src so the blogger knows it must process the tag src, then I wrote '"text text text" + data:variable_of_the_blog + "textmoretext"'.

It's pretty simple once your practice a little.

Let me know, if it solved your problem.